# Problema en unity con juego de plataformas

Tags: unity3d, unity, motor-de-juego

En la imagen se ven dos bloques de baldosas,un bloque a la izquierda y uno a la derecha.En el centro hay otras dos baldosas que se mueven de un bloque al otro gracias a una animación que cree.El jugador maneja al oso,cuando subo con el oso a una de las baldosas en movimiento para ir al otro bloque de baldosas este no se mueve como se mueve la baldosa sino que se pone encima y si lo dejo quieto la baldosa avanza y el se queda en el sitio que está hasta que se cae de la baldosa.Lo que quiero hacer es que la baldosa transporte al oso.Alguien sabe que debo hacer?Gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La baldosa la estas moviendo con una animacion, o sea, estas modificando su Transform.position y este no afecta a la fisica.
Lo que tenes que hacer es agregarle un RigidBody a la baldosa y configurarlo como Kinematic.
Para moverlo vas a tener que crear un script que se encargue de eso.
Saludos

Comment: SO está pensado para usuarios novatos y experimentados, te recomiendo a leer [answer], pues la zona de respuestas no es espacio para hacer recomendaciones

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es esperar a tener 50 puntos y dejarle un comentario indicándole que lea [ask], para que de esta manera mejore su pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné,usando transform.parent.Tienes que hacer que el oso pase a ser hijo de la baldosa cuando entra en contacto con ella.

Comment: @HéctorHuertas Esa no es la forma correcta de resolverlo, para movimientos con física se usan los RigidBody y Colliders o tenes que crear tu propio "motor" de física. Los desplazamientos por Transform son para elementos sin colliders, que no requieren ser afectados o afectar a la posición de otro GameObject. Si bien hacer Transform.Parent te sirvió, no es la mejor opción ya que a futuro puede traerte complicaciones y falta de flexibilidad.

Comment: @LucasgabrielBica entiendo lo que dices pero yo tampoco usaba transform.translate para mover las baldosas,simplemente se mueven por la animación. Y otra cosa si tienes un cuerpo con un riggidbody y un collider puedes usar transform para moverlo en el caso de que tengas marcados isKinematic,no es que puedas es que debes porque si usas las fisicas para moverlo puedo dar problemas de rendimiento